# CSS Every first specific tags simplifier

Tags: css, list, simplification

I would like to know if there is a simpler way to achieve what I need:

**For h2 ,p, ul, [and eventually more]**

```
.left > h2:first-child,
.left > div:first-child > h2:first-child,
.left > p:first-child,
.left > div:first-child > p:first-child,
.left > ul:first-child,
.left > div:first-child > ul:first-child
```

**Something that would be like:**

```
.left > [LIST OF TAGS]:first-child,
.left > div:first-child > [LIST OF TAGS]:first-child
```

Thank you

Comment: In selectors level 4 we can use [`:matches()`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#matches) pseudo-class to achieve that (`.left > :matches(h2, p, div):first-child`) but as of writing it not supported by common web browsers. You might want to consider using CSS pre-processors such as Sass, Less or Stylus.

Comment: Thank you @HashemQolami ! I think you are right. I could use it plus -moz-any()
:-webkit-any() but need separate lines. It will probably be simplier to list them all as before.

Comment: In case the first-child elements in `.left` can only be those in the list, you could use `.left > :not(div):first-child, .left > div:first-child > :first-child`. But probably that's not the case.

Comment: Thank you @Oriol. It's what I tryed first but finaly realized I needed it only on specifics tags.